# date formatting using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

This is json data

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "SummaryPlanDescritionStartDate": "10-20-2015",
            "SummaryPlanDescritionEndDate": "11-20-2015",
            "PdfLink": "http://",
            "BenefitAtAGlanceStartDate": "09-20-2016",
            "BenefitAtAGlanceEndDate": "12-20-2016"
        }
    ]
}
```

to display in html
I want above dates as oct 20 -2015

Comment: It should have been a simple google search to find the built in date filter

Answer (score 1):

you want to use filter
something like this

```
`<div ng-bind="BenefitAtAGlanceStartDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'></div>`
```

Read the documentation here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date